# How to inject value to a bean in spring test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

i have a question here, please give some ideas.

I have two beans. FaceComparisonServerImpl depends on FaceServer.
When i want to test. I want to change the String in my 'FaceServer' bean.

```
@Service        
public class FaceComparisonServerImpl implements FaceComparisonServer {
            
    @Autowired
    private FaceServer faceServer;

    @Override
    public FaceComparsionInfo getServerInfo() {
        String serverInfo = faceServer.getServerInfo();
        ...

    }
         
}

@Component
public class FaceServer {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    //Not final, just to test.
    private String version = "1.0";
    private static final String CODE = "code";
    private static final String MESSAGE = "message";
    //Final
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8066/api/ZKComparison";
}
```

Bellow is my test code.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class FaceServerTestByTyler {

    @Autowired
    private FaceComparisonServer faceComparisonServer;

    @Test
    public void getServerInfo(){
        //How can i modify the value of SERVER_URL in faceServer？
        FaceComparsionInfo serverInfo = faceComparisonServer.getServerInfo();
        System.out.println(serverInfo);
    }
}
```

My question is:
How can i modified the value of 'version' and 'SERVER_URL' in @Bean(faceServer)?

Thanks you!

Comment: (my) options (with prio): 1. make it a proeprty!;) 2. mock it. 3. `(java.lang.reflect)`ion.

Answer (score 2):

You need create FaceServer mock bean for test configuration.
And override required methods

```
@Configuration
Class TestConfig{
@Bean
@Primary
public FaceServer faceServer() {
  return new FaceServer() {
    
 @override
 public String getServerInfo(){
return "required info";
  }
  };
}
}
```

Comment: This should work. And if it doesn't then you can also look into @TestConfiguration.

Comment: I had two classes in the same package, `NormalClass` for normal running and `MockClass extends NormalClass` for testing, Spring complained that it couldn't pick between the two beans during JUnit tests: the `@Primary` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to customize the values is to make them Spring properties:

```java
@Component
public class FaceServer {

    @Value("${faceServer.version}")
    private String version;
    @Value("${faceServer.url}")
    private String serverUrl;

    // ...
}
```

You can either have default values for the `@Value` annotations or use some default property values in `application.yml`.

Now just override those properties in your test with the values you want:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "faceServer.version=1.0",
    "faceServer.url=http://127.0.0.1:8066/api/ZKComparison"
})
public class FaceServerTestByTyler {

    @Autowired
    private FaceComparisonServer faceComparisonServer;

    // ...
}
```

However...

The second option is to make your classes more unit-testable. Prefer construction injection over field injection, and you can test your classes more independently.

```java
@Service        
public class FaceComparisonServerImpl implements FaceComparisonServer {
            
    private final FaceServer faceServer;

    public FaceComparisonServerImpl(FaceServer faceServer) {
        this.faceServer = faceServer;
    }

    @Override
    public FaceComparsionInfo getServerInfo() {
        String serverInfo = faceServer.getServerInfo();
        // ...

    }     
}
```

This now becomes unit-testable:

```java
public class FaceServerTestByTyler {

    private FaceComparisonServer faceComparisonServer;
    private FaceServer faceServer;

    @BeforeEach
    public setup() {
        faceServer = mock(FaceServer.class);
        faceComparisonServer = new FaceComparisonServer(faceServer);
    }

    @Test
    public void getServerInfo() {
        when(faceServer.getServerInfo()).thenReturn(xxx);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The second option ends up with a test that runs much faster than any solutions that suggest to create a mock bean through a test configuration.